# how to solve the issue “Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 137” in Unity on MacOS?

Tags: firebase, macos, unity-game-engine

We are using Unity Editor Version 2021.3.18f1

We are working on one unity project. But when we open the project in Unity Editor (on mac system), we are getting following error

“Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 137”

And sometimes, other error is appearing as below,

“Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2.”

With this error we are not able to play the game in unity editor.
Could anyone help in resolving this issue.

I tried following ways to resolve the issue, but issue was not resolved

1. I deleted Bee folder and open the project again.
2. I deleted Library folder and open the project again.

But I am still getting the issue and I am not able to play the game in Unity Editor.

Comment: Do you find solution regarding this error?

Comment: No. I searched on internet, but didn't find proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

From my side, I have performed these 2 steps and it worked for me:

1. Deleted Library folder content
2. Upgraded Unity 2021.3.25f1 to Unity 2022.2.20f1

Project is opened without any kind of errors.

Comment: Good. But 2022.2.20f1 is not LTS version. Is it ok to work with this version?

Comment: I am using firebase version 8.9.0 and it is mandatory to use this firebase version. I tried to use latest unity version 2022.3.1f1 but I am getting another error. With this new error I am not able to make a build.

Comment: All these things little tricky, before Unity version upgrade deleting Library folder content become useful to me. So complete new Library folder data generated for new Unity version with first opening.